# function call in ng-model AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="row in skuDetails">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <md-input-container class="md-block" style="margin-bottom: 6px;">
        <label style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; line-height: .75;">
        Mrp 
      </label> 
      <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="getMrp(row.mrp)"
      ng-readonly="true"> 
   </md-input-container>
</div>
</div>
```

skuDetails contains mrp. I need to divide mrp by 100 and assign it to ng-model.Which when i did got an error but value got assigned. Therefore tried with  function,I came through same error.Is there any way that i can use expression in ng-model?

Controller

```
scope.getMrp = function(mrp) {
        var value = mrp/100;
        return value;
    }
```

Error:Expression 'getMrp(row.mrp)' is non-assignable. Element:

Comment: what you want to achieve here, you could do `ng-value="getMrp(row.mrp)"`, but there you will lost two way binding...

Comment: @PankajParkar I need the assign the input (text) as row.mrp/100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to pass a function to ng-model.

Assign to a $scope value and you can bind the $scope variable.

```
$scope.myval;
scope.getMrp = function(mrp) {
        var value = mrp/100;
        $scope.myval = value;
}
```

and then,

```
<input type="text" ng-init="getMrp(row.mrp)" name="input" ng-model="myval"
      ng-readonly="true">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**ng-init()**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive evaluates the given expression(s) on initial load.

```
<input type="text" name="input" ng-init="row.mrp=getMrp(row.mrp);" ng-model="row.mrp"
      ng-readonly="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to pass a function to ng-model.

you can use ng-change.

Answer (score 0):

ng-init is your solution like everyone answered. But they didn't noticed it's a boucle in ng-repeat so use the index to initialize them.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="row in skuDetails track by $index">
  <div class="col-md-2" ng-init="setCustomMrp(row.mrp, $index)">
    <md-input-container class="md-block" style="margin-bottom: 6px;">
        <label style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; line-height: .75;">
        Mrp 
      </label> 
      <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="customMrp[$index]"
      ng-readonly="true"> 
   </md-input-container>
</div>
</div>
```

and in the js file :

```
scope.customMrp = []; 
scope.setCustomMrp = function(mrp, index) {
   customMrp[index] = mrp/100;
}
```